# Possible to determine if a method is called by a derived class or directly as itself? C#

Tags: c#

Is there any direct way to determine if a method in a base class (not an abstract) is called by a derived class or explicitly from somewhere that has created an instance of base class?

Comment: You can walk the stack. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you mean 'determine if a method is called', you mean to determine it *after* method was invoked, or inside the method itself ?:

Comment: @Micky Thanks for the tip

Comment: Why does a method need to know that? Methods that act differently based on their calling context sound like a maintenance nightmare to me...

Comment: @Fabjan Determine inside the method itself. Are there any useful scenarios for determining after a method was invoked? And how would i do it in that case?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thank you, i completely agree with you. But i need some way to do some kind of sorting, and the most logical way seems to be to determine if the method is called by the base class or not

Comment: If you agree with @PieterWitvoet why are you doing this?

Comment: @CJC: If you explain your original problem then perhaps people here can offer a better solution. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet the problem is an obscure one, and i didnt want to post any complicated questions. I have example foo class which accesses a bunch of hardware selected via a interface. Then foo class is wrapped by foobar and another class which wraps that which is foobarbazz class. All of them access a method inside foo class either implicitly or explicitly. The problem is this method is accessing a communication channel, and when it is called, there is an expected reply. However this reply is primitive, just a simple OK>, so i need to internally keep track of each access with its corresponding

Comment: @PieterWitvoet reply. So i need to keep track of who is sending, and the response of each sent command. and for the base method in foo class, i also need to keep a queue for all commands that access it at a primitive level.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the requirement is.  The need for code like this says to me a redesign is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is to use reflection:

```
public virtual void MyBaseClassMethod()
{
    var currType = this.GetType();
    if (currType == typeof(MyBaseClass))
    { 
        // base class instantiated directly.
    }
}
```

Comment: You would be better off with Fabjan answer, it's cleaner.

Comment: Really? In Fabjan's case, class `A` needs to know about class `B`. That's not good.

Comment: @Mick yes, but in Fabjan's solution, `class A` needs to know that `B` is defined somewhere. In my solution, that knowledge is not required.

Comment: Seems like there's logic going in MyBaseClassMethod that already knows about Class B anyway.  If you're going to hack, you might as well go all the way.

Comment: I have no idea why either this question or this answer are being upvoted..... I'd be wanting to fire a programmer who found either useful

Comment: @Mick yeah as well as the programmers who don't use design patterns should be fired. In my honest opinion, reflection is not bad when it is used wisley and with full awarness of drawbacks / limits / risks. The life-scenarios often are not perfect and we had to work on other's code that is badly-designed and hacks are the only way to use it..

Comment: @nopeflow i have a friend who is actually a talented animator / artist who is getting into C# in unity.  He recently remarked to me that in his belief OOP and OOD is a mistake, that it's over complicated and un-needed and a general abuse of time and money by developers.  Whilst I completely disagree, I think its this sort of code that adds legitimacy to those sorts of comments.  My advice.... if you're going to hack, stick to procedural programming don't use OOP constructs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the code you could do something like this...

```
public MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override void MyPublicMethod()
    {
        MyPrivateMethod(false);
    }
}

public MyBaseClass   
{
    public virtual void MyPublicMethod()
    {
        MyInternalMethod(true);
    }

    protected void MyInternalMethod(bool isInternal)
    {
        // If you're planning to use isInternal to change the logic based
        // on whether this code has been invoked in the base or subclass
        // you would be infinitely better off overriding that code in the
        // subclass. Or better still don't use generalization at all and
        // use an injection framework and create several implementations
        // of an interface.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mike I have thought about this but i didnt want my derived class to have to pass any parameters. I needed transparency from that. nopeflow's answer seems to be what i am looking for

Comment: @CJC It shouldn't need to.  The derived class should be able to augment or alter the functionality through overrides