# How to find the class from which the method was called in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class `MainClass` with method `MainMethod`. I created more classes which iherit from this class. I would like to add a line to `MainMethod` which will print the name of class of object from which this method was called. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to determine if a method is called by a derived class or directly as itself? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074862/possible-to-determine-if-a-method-is-called-by-a-derived-class-or-directly-as-it)

Comment: What is the purpose? Just logging or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute) and the other goodies discussed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information